# Grails byte array and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, grails, arrays, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to implement the [Simple Avatar Uploader](http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader) on my User domain class but I seem to have encountered a conflicting issue with grails implementation of `byte[]` and PostgreSQL. I have implemented it exactly as the plugin page suggests but on compilation I get the error:

```
Error: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE user ADD avatar bytea(16384): ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "bytea"
```

I have found some help suggesting that [PostgreSQL does not accept a size modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976368/heroku-migration-type-modifier-is-not-allowed-for-type-bytea) but removing the `maxSize: 16384` constraint only leads to the exact same error with a different size:

```
Error: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE user ADD avatar bytea(255): ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "bytea"
```

So it seems that grails will automatically set the size to 255 if no `maxSize` is provided. Is there a way to override this? Or perhaps a more suitable data type for byte arrays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was directly responsible or not but we are using [Grails Database Migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration/) and we solved the issue by editing the latest migration script changing the line

```
column(name: "avatar", type: "bytea(255)")
```

to

```
column(name: "avatar", type: "bytea")
```